# ERROR 404 js file not found

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

**Html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="{% static "js/fillform.js" %}" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        yo man ssup
        <button type="button" id="button">
            click
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and upon loading it gives error

> [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 16ms]

And project tree -

```
bio
-- static
    |-- bio
        |-- js
            |-- template
-- template
    |--bio
        |-- index.html
```

How to solve this error.?

Comment: What is the `BASE_DIR` set to? Also make sure you `import OS` in your settings.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your project directory layout it looks like you are missing `bio` from your path:

```
{% static "bio/js/fillform.js" %}
```